# Knockoutjs subscribe to a button click?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to call a function when clicking submit button from form.

```
<div id="myBrowser" data-bind="with: QuestionFilter">
<form name="Homeworks" data-bind="submit: searchMeNow">
<button data-bind="click: $root.submit, clickBubble: false">Search</button>
```

`searchMeNow` is a function inside of the `QuestionFilter` function.  Can I call it with the click: binding?  If not, can I somehow subscribe to the button like an observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one:

Html:

```
<div id="myBrowser" data-bind="with: QuestionFilter">
<form name="Homeworks" data-bind="submit: searchMeNow">
<button data-bind="click: $root.submit, clickBubble: false">Search</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ViewModel = function(){

    function QuestionFilter(){
        var self = this;
        self.searchMeNow = function(){
        };
    }

    return{
        submit: function(){
            alert("Hello world");
        },
        QuestionFilter:function(){
            return new QuestionFilter();
        }
    }; 
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here's full [version](http://jsfiddle.net/UJQp8/2/)

Comment: I didn't quite understand setting functions as properties of the parent function. Thanks man!